# CodeIgniter Routing and 404 Custom Errors

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-routing, codeigniter-2

I use CodeIgniter.

I route certain urls to different files based on the structure of url using the routes.php file.  Everything has been working fine.

However, a few months ago, i thought i would add a custom 404 page.  I did and things appeared to be working fine.

HOWEVER, i have just realised that every page on my site (except the home page) gives a server response of 404 error and yet displays to the human user the correct page as the custom page!

I have no idea how that's happening but it's obviously a nightmare as i am now not indexed from all search engine listings!!!  Domain is http://citylightstours.com

ROUTES.PHP

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| URI ROUTING
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| This file lets you re-map URI requests to specific controller functions.
|
| Typically there is a one-to-one relationship between a URL string
| and its corresponding controller class/method. The segments in a
| URL normally follow this pattern:
|
|   example.com/class/method/id/
|
| In some instances, however, you may want to remap this relationship
| so that a different class/function is called than the one
| corresponding to the URL.
|
| Please see the user guide for complete details:
|
|   http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html
|
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| RESERVED ROUTES
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| There area two reserved routes:
|
|   $route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
|
| This route indicates which controller class should be loaded if the
| URI contains no data. In the above example, the "welcome" class
| would be loaded.
|
|   $route['404_override'] = 'errors/page_missing';
|
| This route will tell the Router what URI segments to use if those provided
| in the URL cannot be matched to a valid route.
|
*/

$route['default_controller'] = "content";
$route['en/(:num)/(:any)'] = "content/en/$1";
$route['de/(:num)/(:any)'] = "content/de/$1";
$route['es/(:num)/(:any)'] = "content/es/$1";
$route['it/(:num)/(:any)'] = "content/it/$1";
$route['ar/(:num)/(:any)'] = "content/ar/$1";
$route['404_override'] = '';


/* End of file routes.php */
/* Location: ./application/config/routes.php */
```

.HTACCESS file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Development
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|scripts|styles|vendor|robots\.txt)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Better website experience for IE users
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    BrowserMatch MSIE ie
    Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1" env=ie
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Webfont access
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|font.css)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Proper MIME type for all files
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# audio
AddType audio/ogg                      oga ogg

# video
AddType video/ogg                      .ogv
AddType video/mp4                      .mp4
AddType video/webm                     .webm

# Proper svg serving. Required for svg webfonts on iPad
#   twitter.com/FontSquirrel/status/14855840545
AddType     image/svg+xml              svg svgz 
AddEncoding gzip                       svgz

# webfonts                             
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject  eot
AddType font/truetype                  ttf
AddType font/opentype                  otf
AddType application/x-font-woff        woff

# assorted types                                      
AddType image/x-icon                   ico
AddType image/webp                     webp
AddType text/cache-manifest            appcache manifest
AddType text/x-component               htc
AddType application/x-chrome-extension crx
AddType application/x-xpinstall        xpi
AddType application/octet-stream       safariextz

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# gzip compression
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s,?\s(gzip|deflate)?|X{4,13}|~{4,13}|-{4,13})$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
    RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "^(?!.*\.ogg$|.*\.ogv$|.*\.mp4$).+" >

# html, txt, css, js, json, xml, htc:
<IfModule filter_module>
  FilterDeclare   COMPRESS
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type /text/(html|css|javascript|plain|x(ml|-component))/
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type /application/(javascript|json|xml|x-javascript)/
  FilterChain     COMPRESS
  FilterProtocol  COMPRESS  change=yes;byteranges=no
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

# webfonts and svg:
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|svg)$" >
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Expires headers (for better cache control)
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on

# Perhaps better to whitelist expires rules? Perhaps.
  ExpiresDefault                          "access plus 1 month"

# cache.appcache needs re-requests in FF 3.6 (thx Remy ~Introducing HTML5)
  ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest       "access plus 0 seconds"

# your document html 
  ExpiresByType text/html                 "access plus 0 seconds"

# data
  ExpiresByType text/xml                  "access plus 0 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xml           "access plus 0 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/json          "access plus 0 seconds"

# rss feed
  ExpiresByType application/rss+xml       "access plus 1 hour"

# favicon (cannot be renamed)
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon              "access plus 1 week" 

# media: images, video, audio
  ExpiresByType image/gif                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/png                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpg                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg                "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType audio/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/mp4                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/webm                "access plus 1 month"

# htc files  (css3pie)
  ExpiresByType text/x-component          "access plus 1 month"

# webfonts
  ExpiresByType font/truetype             "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType font/opentype             "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff   "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml             "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"

# css and javascript
  ExpiresByType text/css                  "access plus 2 months"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript    "access plus 2 months"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript           "access plus 2 months"

  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Cache-Control "public"
  </IfModule>

</IfModule>

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# ETag removal
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

FileETag None

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Stop screen flicker in IE on CSS rollovers
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# The following directives stop screen flicker in IE on CSS rollovers - in
# combination with the "ExpiresByType" rules for images (see above). If
# needed, un-comment the following rules.

# BrowserMatch "MSIE" brokenvary=1
# BrowserMatch "Mozilla/4.[0-9]{2}" brokenvary=1
# BrowserMatch "Opera" !brokenvary
# SetEnvIf brokenvary 1 force-no-vary

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^citylightstours\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://citylightstours.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]
```

I have a MY_Router.php file to handle customer 404 pages and wonder whether this is setting a 404 http status incorrectly ??

MY_Router.php file:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Router extends CI_Router {

    var $error_controller = 'error';
    var $error_method_404 = 'error_404';

    function My_Router()
    {
        parent::CI_Router();
    }

    // this is just the same method as in Router.php, with show_404() replaced by $this->error_404();
    function _validate_request($segments)
    {
        // Does the requested controller exist in the root folder?
        if (file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$segments[0].EXT))
        {
            return $segments;
        }

        // Is the controller in a sub-folder?
        if (is_dir(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$segments[0]))
        {       
            // Set the directory and remove it from the segment array
            $this->set_directory($segments[0]);
            $segments = array_slice($segments, 1);

            if (count($segments) > 0)
            {
                // Does the requested controller exist in the sub-folder?
                if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$this->fetch_directory().$segments[0].EXT))
                {
                    return $this->error_404();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $this->set_class($this->default_controller);
                $this->set_method('index');

                // Does the default controller exist in the sub-folder?
                if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$this->fetch_directory().$this->default_controller.EXT))
                {
                    $this->directory = '';
                    return array();
                }
            }

            return $segments;
        }

        // Can't find the requested controller...
        return $this->error_404();
    }

    function error_404()
    {
        $this->directory = "";
        $segments = array();
        $segments[] = $this->error_controller;
        $segments[] = $this->error_method_404;
        return $segments;
    }

    function fetch_class()
    {
        // if method doesn't exist in class, change
        // class to error and method to error_404
        $this->check_method();

        return $this->class;
    }

    function check_method()
    {
        $ignore_remap = true;

        $class = $this->class;
        if (class_exists($class))
        {   
            // methods for this class
            $class_methods = array_map('strtolower', get_class_methods($class));

            // ignore controllers using _remap()
            if($ignore_remap && in_array('_remap', $class_methods))
            {
                return;
            }

            if (! in_array(strtolower($this->method), $class_methods))
            {
                $this->directory = "";
                $this->class = $this->error_controller;
                $this->method = $this->error_method_404;
                include(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$this->fetch_directory().$this->error_controller.EXT);
            }
        }
    }

    function show_404()
    {
        include(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$this->fetch_directory().$this->error_controller.EXT);
        call_user_func(array($this->error_controller, $this->error_method_404));
    }

}

/* End of file MY_Router.php */
/* Location: ./system/application/libraries/MY_Router.php */
```

Can someone please help!??

Thanks

Comment: I think it is finding the page and returning it but setting a server response code of 404.  Where would it set that in CodeIgniter????

Answer (score 0):

Your Routes needs fixing : -

```
$route['en/(:num)/(:any)'] = "content/en/$1";
$route['de/(:num)/(:any)'] = "content/de/$1";
$route['es/(:num)/(:any)'] = "content/es/$1";
$route['it/(:num)/(:any)'] = "content/it/$1";
$route['ar/(:num)/(:any)'] = "content/ar/$1";
```

Have a read at this : -

http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/routing.html

According to your routing you have a controller for each language. for example(enController,deController,esController etc... ) which i am presuming you don't have that you just have a content controller.

The response you are looking for can be found here : -

https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/URI-Language-Identifier

Comment: Hi codenathan,  thanks for taking the time to respond.  I read that article and cant see anything wrong with my route as it is - it links to the content class and the language method.  I dont think it specifies different content controllers - just one controller with different methods within it...?  In any event i removed reference to the language aspects of the route but i still get the 404 server response and the correct page being displayed as human custom page....any ideas what's going on??

Comment: Sorry i incorrectly read that could you post your content controller code?

Comment: hi codenathan, i could but i dont think it's got anything to do with my content controller.  that all works fine as it correctly goes and gets the correct page data from the database and correctly displays it.  the prob is that it's displaying it with a http status of 404 instead of 200.  I have a custom error page and think it might have something to do with the MY_Router.php file i have in order to do this custom 404.  I will post the MYRouter code...